# Fix the height and width of a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview in my page that displays records from database.

I need to know how to fix its height and width?

This is I have tried so far:

```
<asp:GridView CssClass="donorsGridView"
```

CSS

```
.donorsGridView{
    width:200px;
    height:50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the height and width for gridview directly like this

```
<asp:GridView  Width="200px" Height="50px"/>
```

Edit : To enable paging

```
<asp:gridview allowpaging="true" pagesize="10" />
```

Comment: Can I Limit number of rows in gridview in each page(paging is enabled.)

Comment: @user3110335 If it didn't work try setting `height` and `width` for outer tag and yes if you want to enable paging you can just set `allowpaging="true"` and `pagesize="10 or any number you want"`

Comment: Is there any way to fix its width?

Comment: @user3110335 Did you try setting the width for the parent tag?

Comment: Its parent is <asp:Content

Comment: I just added gridview inside a div and set its width but that gridview still doesnt stays inside that limit

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47446/discussion-between-electricrouge-and-user3110335)

Comment: @user3110335 I just tested your code I think the problem is in your masterpage